# Getting User with Highest Amount

Tags: mysql

I have a table full of users and, using the below query, I'm able to get the result of the highest score divided by points:

`SELECT MAX(points/score) FROM table`

However, I'd like to grab the user associated with the result; any suggestions?

Comment: What is the schema of the table?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table
 ORDER BY points/score DESC
 LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

just order by `points/score` and limit the result to one:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  table
ORDER BY
  points/score DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: That returned the first user in the column, rather than the player the result is associated with.